# AWK - import IF conditions from file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, if-statement, awk

I'm trying to use `awk` to parse some files and extract only the records that match a set of regular expressions. So I'm trying to pass the set of regular expressions to an `IF` conditional in this way:

```
$  awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; IGNORECASE=1} NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {for (i in a){ if(i) {print $0}}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

This is because `file1.txt` has the list of regex that I want to be searched in `file2.txt`. For convenience, let us suppose that the two files look like this:

```
$ cat file1.txt

  $4 ~ $2 "foo[^.]*" $3
  $4 ~ $3 "[^.]*foo" $2

$ cat file2.txt

  1|this|bar|In this line, bar is before foo|
  2|not|here|Here, foo is before. Not|
  3|First|Second|First comes foo then bar comes second.|
```

So, in this particular example, my regular expressions are trying to match the words from field `$2` and `$3` with the string `foo` in-between  and within the same sentence (that's why I'm using `[^.]*` in field `$4`. Since I'm not interested if `$1` comes before `$2` or viceversa (as long as they are in the same sentence with `foo` in-between) I have the two regex that match both cases and only the third record should be printed.

Since I'm trying to find many patterns in field `$4` in many files, my first approach was to make a list, but perhaps there are other ways around

I'd appreciate any help and comments.

Comment: Before trying to help you do something that on the surface makes no sense to do - why do you want to do that instead of just including the conditions in the awk script?

Comment: @EdMorton: Because I'm trying to find a lot of regex like those in the exmple in a lot of files. So it's easier to write 50 regex of length ~ 50 chars than writing 50 blocks of awk code of length 300 chars. Perhaps I'm not getting your idea.

Comment: I guess not as I can't imagine what you're thinking of when you talk about writing more code if it's in the script than if it's in a file. I posted an answer to show the right approach, maybe that'll help.

Comment: Why don't you use `awk -f file1.txt`?  You would need to add the BEGIN clause to the file, but ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. Just list the conditions in the script:

```
BEGIN {FS="|"; IGNORECASE=1}
$4 ~ $2 "foo[^.]*" $3
$4 ~ $3 "[^.]*foo" $2
```

Assuming the above is stored in a file `foo.awk`, execute it as `awk -f foo.awk file2.txt`.

Or could just do this with your existing `file1.txt`:

```
awk -F"|" -v IGNORECASE=1 -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

Your regexps are buggy, btw. We can fix those after you settle on the approach but I THINK what you're trying to express is:

```
$4 ~ ("\\<" $2 "\\>.*\\<foo\\>.*\\<" $3 "\\>")
$4 ~ ("\\<" $3 "\\>.*\\<foo\\>.*\\<" $2 "\\>")
```

which could be combined into:

```
$4 ~ ( ("\\<" $2 "\\>.*\\<foo\\>.*\\<" $3 "\\>") || ("\\<" $3 "\\>.*\\<foo\\>.*\\<" $2 "\\>") )
```

if you like.

The above is using GNU awk for word delimiters. Just be aware it can fail if $2 or $3 contains RE metacharacters.

Comment: The second solution is what I need, so thanks. And I'm not sure if I really want the strings in the regex to be word-delimited since in my real data set I can find the terms forming compund terms. For example, I'm looking if there are any reports of warfarin co adminstered with aspirin that resulted in death of a patient. And I have found reports like this one: Warfarin-aspirin coadministration may increase the risk of severe bleeding... So I think that the search would be more comprehensive the other way.

Comment: Using word delimiters around `warfarin` and `aspirin` WOULD find `warfarin-aspirin`. No regexp would find `coadministration` given `co adminstered` if that was a goal. For your particular problem you might want to consider using come kind of phonetic encoding for your words (e.g. google "Soundex") so as to avoid not matching when the names of the drugs are mis-spelled.